# Mysql need to select records with no dublicats on multiple fields comparison

Tags: mysql, select

I have a single table 'deals' with structure and 7 records in ...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `deals` (
  `deal_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fromCity` varchar(75) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
  `toCity` varchar(75) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `outbound` date NOT NULL,
  `inbound` date NOT NULL,
  `airline` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `CPM` decimal(8,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`deal_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=719971 ;


INSERT INTO `deals` (`deal_id`, `fromCity`, `toCity`, `outbound`, `inbound`, `airline`, `CPM`, `created`) VALUES
(719968, 'Hong Kong', 'Taegu', '2017-07-23', '2017-07-17', 'Air China', '4.80', '2017-07-02 05:48:05'),
(719967, 'Hong Kong', 'Taegu', '2017-07-23', '2017-07-17', 'Air China', '4.81', '2017-07-02 05:48:04'),
(719966, 'Hong Kong', 'Montreal', '2017-07-23', '2017-07-18', 'Air China', '4.70', '2017-07-02 05:48:04'),
(719965, 'Hong Kong', 'Montreal', '2017-07-23', '2017-07-18', 'Air China', '4.75', '2017-07-02 05:48:04'),
(719964, 'Busan', 'Saipan', '2017-07-23', '2017-07-19', 'Air China', '4.60', '2017-07-02 05:48:04'),
(719969, 'Hong Kong', 'Taegu', '2017-07-23', '2017-07-17', 'Air China', '4.82', '2017-07-02 05:49:04'),
(719970, 'Hong Kong', 'Saipan', '2017-07-23', '2017-07-17', 'Jeju Air', '4.85', '2017-07-02 05:49:04');
```

I need to select all records with no dublicats based on few fields like fromCity, toCity, outbound and inbound.

So I want to select every rows but if selected row has a dublicats with same fromCity, toCity, outbound and inbound values I need to select only first or only last from dublicats.

This is main query that I am use for getting all records with airline = 'Air China':

```
SELECT 
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS fromCity, toCity, inbound, outbound, airline, CPM, created 
FROM 
    deals 
WHERE 
    airline LIKE '%Air China%' 
ORDER BY 
    CPM
```

This query return 6 rows from 7 because only six rows has needed airline.
But you can see in that results 3 dublicats with same fromCity, toCity, inbound, outbound fields.
[all records with dublicats and neede airline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBTXi.png)

I need to select only 3 recors from there. This records I need.
[Needed rows. First do not have a dublicats. Second have a one dublicat. And third have a two dublicats.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwqwc.png)

Also I was try to use this query to select without dublicats...

```
SELECT
    minid, deals.deal_id, 
    deals.fromCity, deals.toCity, deals.inbound, deals.outbound,
    deals.airline, deals.CPM, deals.created
  FROM
    deals
  inner join 
    (select 
        min(deal_id) minid, deal_id, 
        fromCity, toCity, inbound, outbound, airline, CPM, created 
     from deals 
     group by fromCity, toCity, inbound, outbound
     having count(1) > 1) 
  as duplicates
  on (duplicates.fromCity = deals.fromCity
  and duplicates.toCity = deals.toCity
  and duplicates.inbound = deals.inbound
  and duplicates.outbound = deals.outbound
  and duplicates.deal_id <> deals.deal_id)

  WHERE 
    deals.airline LIKE  '%Air China%'

  ORDER BY
    CPM
```

But this query returns only that rows that have a dublicats. Also if row has a not single dublicats it is returns few rows instead one with no dublicats.

The desired result should be as follows:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+------+---------------------+
| deal_id | fromCity  | toCity   | outbound   | inbound    | airline   | CPM  | created             |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+------+---------------------+
|  719964 | Busan     | Saipan   | 2017-07-23 | 2017-07-19 | Air China | 4.60 | 2017-07-02 05:48:04 |
|  719966 | Hong Kong | Montreal | 2017-07-23 | 2017-07-18 | Air China | 4.70 | 2017-07-02 05:48:04 |
|  719967 | Hong Kong | Taegu    | 2017-07-23 | 2017-07-17 | Air China | 4.81 | 2017-07-02 05:48:04 |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------+------+---------------------+
```

Thank you for help. With regards.

Comment: What would the desired result look like

Comment: I think you ask about this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwqwc.png

Comment: "only first or last" which?

Comment: last would be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM deals a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(deal_id) deal_id
         FROM deals x 
         JOIN  
            ( SELECT fromcity
                   , tocity
                   , outbound
                   , inbound
                   , MIN(created) created 
                FROM deals 
               WHERE airline = 'Air China'
               GROUP 
                  BY fromcity
                   , tocity
                   , outbound
                   , inbound
            ) y 
           ON y.fromcity = x.fromcity 
          AND y.tocity = x.tocity 
          AND y.outbound = x.outbound 
          AND y.inbound = x.inbound 
          AND y.created = x.created
        GROUP
           BY x.fromcity
            , x.tocity
            , x.outbound
            , x.inbound
            , x.airline
            , x.created
     ) b
    ON b.deal_id = a.deal_id;
```

Comment: Highest id would be great.

Comment: How you paste the mysql data in that pretty characters block?

Comment: I do it by indenting text a minimum of 4 spaces.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT
    fromCity,
    toCity,
    inbound,
    outbound,
    airline,
    CPM,
    created 
FROM 
    deals 
WHERE 
    airline LIKE '%Air China%' 
    AND created = 
   (
            SELECT 
              created 
            FROM deals 
            GROUP BY fromCity, toCity, inbound, outbound, airline
            ORDER BY created, CPM ASC 
            LIMIT 1
   )
GROUP BY fromCity, toCity, inbound, outbound, airline, created ;
```

With Join

```
SELECT
    d.fromCity, d.toCity, d.inbound, d.outbound, d.airline, d.CPM, d.created 
FROM 
    deals d
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
     created 
  FROM deals 
  GROUP BY fromCity, toCity, inbound, outbound, airline
  LIMIT 1
) as T1
ON (T1.created = d.created AND d.airline LIKE '%Air China%')
GROUP BY d.fromCity, d.toCity, d.inbound, d.outbound, d.airline, d.created;
```

Comment: Will try to have a few test but for first look it is work brilliant. Thank you. I'll notify you with results asap.

Comment: Sorry but CPM field can be different and in that case query work not correct.
Try to change CPM and run again..

Comment: If you give me an example data and example result I can edit this @Yegor

Comment: I was edited example data. Result that I expect youi can see at screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwqwc.png

Comment: Thick that, If Hongkong -> Montreal CPM's are 4.70 and 4.80. Which one we have to select? @Yegor

Comment: You can select lower or higher what you think a best. I am just need to get three deal without dublicats.

Comment: DISTINCT is redundant in the context of a GROUP BY. That aside, this is a hack solution

Comment: Agree with you. Also after I was have some test it is do not returns all records that it is should. Work on.

Comment: It is working but when I was test on big data table it is returns very low records count. I am try to find why now.

Comment: Joın may increase speed. I will edit for JOIN @Yegor

Comment: Answer was edited. It works little bit faster. @Yegor